# Can't install a Grails plugin

Tags: plugins, grails, ws-client

I'm trying to install the ws-client plugin for grails. When I run grails install-plugin ws-client, however, it gets to

```
Resolving plugin ws-client. Please wait...
```

and then it just appears to complete with no further information. I've tried deleting the plugin in the application.properties file (it is appearing there) but it doesn't help.

I know the plugin wasn't successfully installed either because I get an error when trying to import the ws-client.

```
Unable to resolve class groovyx.net.ws.WSClient
```

Does anyone know why it's not properly installing?

Thanks!

**Update:** When I run grails list-plugins -installed ws-client DOES show up, so perhaps it is being installed? But if so, why would the import statement be throwing the resolve error?

**Update:** It was definitely a problem with the installation. I don't know what the problem was, but I have managed to work around it. Posting an answer with the process.

Well I can't post an answer to myself because I need 100 Rep to answer myself in under 8 hours, and I of course only have 99... :)

The answer wound up being to right click "plugins" under the project in STS' Project Explorer window and manually locating the ws-client plugin and marking for installation. I'll post this as an actual answer in 5 hours.

Comment: I upvoted your question so hopefully you can post an answer now. :-)

Comment: i have a similar issue with another plugin. but i dont use STS. is there an alternative solution to this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So for some reason using the

```
grails install-plugin ws-client
```

command wasn't working correctly. I ran it from both the command line and STS's built in terminal. Both gave me the problem of it not completing installation, but not giving an error either.

Anyway, I finally managed to get the plugin installed by right clicking on "plugins" under my project in the STS Project Explorer window. From there you can open "Grails Plugin Manager" and search for ws-client. I selected it for installation and it wound up installing without a hitch.

Still don't know why I couldn't do it from regular command line, but this method worked and got it installed, so hopefully it helps someone else out in the future!

Answer (score 0):

Another way that did work for me (I'm using STS) is to run `grails install-plugin ws-client`  by accessing grails command-line through Ctrl+Alt+Shift+G (Cmd+Alt+Shift+G on Mac)

Also it helps to just "Refresh" the project after installing the plugin and rebuilding it (if you're Automatic Built is turned off)